# Javascript: safe replace function or variable name?

Tags: javascript, rename, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working with some deminified javascript that I want to reverse  engineer. It  would be helpful if I could start giving things variable names. Unfortunately the code has a habit of reusing function and variable names globally and in function scopes, how can I safely replace variable names in these cases in an ast-aware way?

Comment: You could use VS Code built in command "rename symbols" for the variable.

Comment: To the close requestors who clearly think this is trivial. I bet there are edge cases and the code within vscode is near impossible to debug or recompile. But let's see.

Comment: Seems  to be working okay so  far. But the proof will be when  I run stuff again :D

Comment: Code changed by VS Code seemed to work okay.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer, I'm working on. [Here is the code](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/3ffe8cf0d191a32efa1867823fcea4d1/253ab854d037cc9a1ec122f41f031d74f3cba08c):

```js
export const fix = ({path, names}) => {
    const {name} = path.node;
    const to = names[name];
    
    path.scope.rename(name, to);
}

export const traverse = ({push}) =>  {
    const names = {
        a: 'username',
        b: 'password',
    };
    
    const namesKeys = Object.keys(names);
    
    return {
        Identifier(path) {
            const {name} = path.node;
            const bindings = path.scope.getAllBindings();
            
            if (namesKeys.includes(name) && bindings[name])
                push({
                    path,
                    names,
                });
        }
    };
};
```

From:

```js
const a = 'John';
const b = 'Wick';

login();

function login() {
    if (a)
        log(a);

    if (b)
        log(b);
}
```

To:

```js
const username = 'John';
const password = 'Wick';

login();

function login() {
    if (username)
        log(username);

    if (password)
        log(password);
}
```

You can get realtime results in **Putout Editor**, just modify `names` map with a values you need.

Comment: Aha. That might be what I was looking for. It looks like it might be good for some of the other refactoring tasks I was looking into. I want to do a few other bits of deminifying.